# Do I need to use Tornado Futures with Motorengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado

Basically, what is a Futures on Tornado's approach?

I've read on some stackoverflow threads that a tornado coroutine must return a Future, but returning a Future how do my db queries work?

Using Futures will my Tornado app be waiting for the query to return anything like a blocking i/o or it will just dispatch the request and change the context until the query return?

And this Motorengine solution? Do I need to use Futures or just make the queries?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how Tornado works asynchronously. Everytime you yield a Future object, Tornado suspends current coroutine and jumps to the next coroutine. Doing queries synchronous or asynchronous depends on the situation. If your query is fast enough, you can use synchronous driver. Also, keep in mind, jumping between coroutines has a cost, too. If it is not fast enough, you might consider doing asychronous calls.

Comment: and how can I measure this? which way should i take? synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: i'm thinking about building the same api on flask and on tornado and compare both. is this a good way to know if i'm going the right way on async?

Comment: I think first you should have a synchronous solution (like flask). If you are not pleased by synchronous solution, then you should try an asynchronous solution (like tornado). For your asynchronous solution (like tornado), please read my answer (sync/async database driver problem). Remember, Donald Knuth said that, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil in programming.".